# Convert unicode characters in AJAX

Tags: ajax, unicode

I have this searchscript combined with AJAX (Infinite scroll), which is fine.

I can search for anything. Goats, cars, videos, pictures etc. etc. but when it comes to words like "Æble" (means apple), and ANY special character it fails.

Æble = %C3%A6ble

It's annoying because it searches for "%C3%A6ble" instead of "Æble". ALL of my files is saved as UTF-8 and my meta is UTF-8 etc. etc.

What can be wrong?

Comment: How are you getting the query string from the request on your server?

Comment: @MikeSamuel I'm getting the string via a postform. I'm posting it to a file, where I cut some things from the phrase, to secure a bunch of things. I then proceed to send the request to another file, where the string is in the header like: index.php?page=search&q=æble

The AJAX gets the "q" and searches the database.

Comment: You need to urldecode the search string.

Comment: @beerbajay I have tried to decode it. But ut's not the PHP it's wrong with, it's the ajaxfile which is the problem - I think. Because I can print out everything from the header, which will show the word correctly, but as soon as the word passes through the .js file something goes wrong.

Comment: `%C3%A6ble` is correctly encoded for a URL so either you are double encoding the data when you send it to the server or you are failing to decode it in the PHP. We can't tell which as you haven't shown us any of the code.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you. This solved the problem. You were right - I double encoded it by a mistake. 

beerbajay - I have encoded it twice by mistake, so thank you.

Thank all of you.